# Executar o projeto java Maven via terminal?

Tags: java, maven

Eu fiz um projeto Maven no Eclipse, instalei uma dependência do Mahout pelo pom.xml, fiz o código e ele funciona beleza, tá lindo. Mas tenho que executar isso em uma máquina virtual, ou seja sem Eclipse. Como eu executo meu projeto na maquina virtual? Eu tenho um pequena experiência em java sei que é gerado um executável, mas o que exatamente tenho que passar para a maquina virtual e como executar via terminal?

O árvore do meu projeto é esta, o meu código principal está em App.java. data.csv é o arquivo de entrada, o resto foi gerado automaticamente.

```
Recommender/
├── data
│   └── data.csv
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── com
│   │           └── predict
│   │               └── Recommender
│   │                   └── App.java
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── predict
│                   └── Recommender
│                       └── AppTest.java
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   ├── com
    │   │   └── predict
    │   │       └── Recommender
    │   │           └── App.class
    │   └── META-INF
    │       ├── MANIFEST.MF
    │       └── maven
    │           └── com.predict
    │               └── Recommender
    │                   ├── pom.properties
    │                   └── pom.xml
    └── test-classes
        └── com
            └── predict
                └── Recommender
                     └── AppTest.class
```

Eu instalei o maven na maquina virtual executei o Hello World então adicionei meu codigo dentro do App.java e adicionei a dependecia dentro do pom.xml e executei os sequintes codigos:

`mvn package`

`java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App`

Porém meu deu os seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/model/DataModel
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at 
 sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at 
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Já tentou usar `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Mas usando o mvn install teria que reorganizar meus diretorios?

Comment: Então, como está o seu `pom.xml`?

Comment: Faça o teste com o `mvn clean install`. Provavelmente deve dar certo. Se der errado, edite a pergunta para postar o erro.

Comment: Você quer rodar a aplicação com o Maven ou gerar um jar com dependências que rode sem o Maven? No primeiro caso você provavelmente quer usar algo como `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.predict.Recommender.App"`, no segundo há várias opções com plugins do maven, desde gerar um *uber jar* com todas as dependencias até exportar as dependencias para uma pasta lib e gerar um jar com um MANIFEST.MF adequado.

Comment: Eu queria executar a aplicação, não precisa ter o maven isntalado. Mas eu instalei as dependencias atraves do maven